# how to fetch a list from a SQlite database in flutter app

Tags: flutter

I use SQlite database using sqflite package in my Flutter App.
I want to convert a map list to an announcement list, but I have a compilation error

```
    final Database db = await database;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('announcement');
    List<Announcement> announcements = List.generate(maps.length, (i) => {return Announcement.fromMap(maps[i]);});
```

The error is under return Announcement.fromMap(maps[i]): `The return type 'Set<Announcement>' isn't a 'Announcement', as required by the closure's context.dartreturn_of_invalid_type_from_closure)`

please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

It seem you mistakenly placed some brackets around the final line which makes dart treat the argument inside like a set.

Replace

```
List<Announcement> announcements = List.generate(maps.length, (i) => {return Announcement.fromMap(maps[i]);});
```

with

```
List<Announcement> announcements = List.generate(maps.length, (i) => Announcement.fromMap(maps[i]););
```

For context: There are two ways you can write this line. Either with the `(i) => ...` syntax or via the more verbose `(i) {return ...;}` syntax. You mixed those two up.